# My twilio message gets send but i don't see the message

Tags: python, twilio, whatsapp

I am using the Twilio API to send messages to people who have joined my WhatsApp sandbox every 6 hours.
When I check my heroku logs, I can confirm that the messages were sent, since in my code, in the `send_coronavirus_data` function, I print:  `message.sid`, and when I do hero logs, this part tells me that the SIDs were successfully printed

```
020-06-29T12:52:32.737458+00:00 heroku[sendDaily.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-29T12:52:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-29T18:52:36.516514+00:00 app[sendDaily.1]: SMb790af0d488842c2ba0c4dce1268d8e2
2020-06-29T18:52:36.695808+00:00 app[sendDaily.1]: SMcfa9a6bffb2e40e6a77c743417d6577d
2020-06-29T18:52:36.892422+00:00 app[sendDaily.1]: SMe656a05adb5b4162b84db991719858ca
2020-06-29T18:52:37.084771+00:00 app[sendDaily.1]: SMe567ae94c0b645d691d1092f18f6e4e8
2020-06-29T18:52:37.264531+00:00 app[sendDaily.1]: SMecda29592a604d888935b2fc452ae9b3
2020-06-29T18:52:37.448149+00:00 app[sendDaily.1]: SMe4d05871a4d845cdb5fa7f9553eba92b
2020-06-29T18:52:37.614717+00:00 app[sendDaily.1]: SM44a8109900d94c60b82790ca23ad8613
```

The problem is that I don't see the message when I switch to WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 24 hours window for free form messages. After that window, you must use a WhatsApp message template to intimate conversation to the WhatsApp participant and they must respond for the next 24 hour free form window to open. Look in the Twilio console messages logs to see if this is the case.

Comment: I thought i fixed it by going to whatsapp beta and doing the tutorial again. But today i tried to send messages to my whatsapp phone number but i didn't receive the message. Can i have some more info on this 24 hour thing cuz i don't really get it.

Comment: Sure thing, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017773294-Rules-and-Best-Practices-for-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio#h_6dc5a163-8a17-4035-bfb9-dcdf18e3d6d8 and https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates#sending-non-template-messages-within-a-24-hour-session.